# Follow a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` that is populated by a `UIImagePickerControl` button that is in a Cell, I want the cell that is on the end of the collection view to be followed by the screen, but still enable user scrolling

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
NSString* imageString = [image toString];
Screen * screen = [[Screen alloc]init];
screen.imageData = imageString;
[self.project.screens addObject:screen];
long long rowid = [self saveNewImageForScreenToDb:screen];
[self updateTitle:@"" atRowId:rowid];
[self updateTask:@"" atRowId:rowid];


[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:_picker completion:^{
    [_collectionView reloadData];

}];

    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc]initWithIndex:?]; 
   [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath: indexPath.row =?
                                atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight
                                        animated:YES];

}
```

This is the code for the picker, the picker is a button on the end of my 'UICollectioView'. what indexPath must I insert to let the screen scroll to the end where the button is

Comment: Do you want to scroll your CollectionView to the last item i.e UIImagePickerControl button ?

Comment: yes, the code above is when the picker did finish picking an image and adding it to the collection

Comment: You would be adding selected image into an array. `[_collectionView reloadData];
        NSIndexPath *bottomIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:imagesArray.count-1 inSection:0];
      [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath: bottomIndexPath
                                atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight
                                        animated:YES];` Try doing this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be adding selected image into an `NSMutableArray`.Assume your array is `imagesArray`. Scroll your `collectionView` to the last object of `NSMutableArray`. Try adding this code under `didFinishPickingImage` method.

```
[_collectionView reloadData];
NSIndexPath *bottomIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:imagesArray.count-1 inSection:0];
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath: bottomIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:YES];
```